# Windows 7, Create Custom Context Menu for specific drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, context-menu

Environment: Windows 7 64-bit SP1

Goal: Create Right-click context menu only for a specific drive (G:)

I've been attempting to create my own right-click context menu for a specific networked drive. This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/183785/windows-7-context-menu-for-folders-if-folder-contains-certain-filetypes) has been helpful but not working for me in my case.  I can create the menu but as soon as I the "AppliesTo"="System.ItemFolderPathDisplay:~< \"G:\\"" It will not show up at all even when right clicking on the background of the G drive.  I've been trying to use this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Test2YO]
@="&Dir Bkgrd Shell"
"AppliesTo"="System.ItemFolderPathDisplay:~< \"G:\\\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Test2YO\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"
```

I suspect that the System.ItemFolderPathDisplay isn't what I should be using.  Becuase it refers to an item, but I am right clicking a background.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I may accomplish my goal?

Comment: Haven't gone through the document yet, but this was linked from a similar question on the Microsoft forums where someone asked about the possible arguments in creating custom context menus: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Based on what I'm reading right now, is appears that the only arguments applicable to Context Menus is the file type. I may be wrong, but even the custom context menu apps out there specify they only work for different file types.

Comment: @Music2myear Thank you for your response! I'm going to keep looking into it.